# Elementary number theory (HCF)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $$X=a_1x+b_1y$$ $$Y=a_2x+b_2y$$
>   $$a_1 b_2-a_2b_1 =1$$

Then prove that the greatest common divisor of X and Y is same as that of x and y.

Though we can easily see that this is normal equation where $X=(a_1,b_1)$ and $Y=(a_2,b_2)$ but I am not able to go any further in the question to prove the required thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We show (i) If $d$ divides $x$ and $y$, then $d$ divides $X$ and $Y$ and (ii) If $d$ divides $X$ and $Y$, then $d$ divides $x$ and $y$.

Assertion (i) is obvious.

To prove (ii), note that from the first equation, by multiplying through by $b_2$, we have
$$b_2X=a_1b_2x+b_1b_2 y.$$
From the second equation we have 
$$b_1Y=a_2b_1y+b_1b_2y.$$
Subtract. We get
$$b_2X-b_1Y=(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)x=x.$$
Now from $d\mid X$ and $d\mid Y$ we conclude that $d\mid x$.

A similar argument shows that $d\mid y$.

We have shown that $x,y$ and $X,Y$ have the same set of common divisors, and in particular the same *greatest* common divisor.